# magento admin redirecting back to main page of module after massaction

Tags: php, magento

After adding massAction to a new Magento Admin module, I get redirected to the main page for that module instead of where I was last.

As an example: I have a month dropdown menu, so I go select "November", then I select "Page 3" from the pagination. Then when I select and run an action against one or more items, I get redirected back to the current month, page 1.

I added massAction from this post: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/
Here is what I ended up with:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    parent::_prepareMassaction();

    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('value_id');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('deactivate', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('renewals')->__('Deactivate'),
        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDeactivate'),
        'confirm'   => Mage::helper('renewals')->__('Are you sure you want to deactivate these accounts?'),
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

and my controller data:

```
public function massDeactivateAction()
{
    $value_ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('value_id');

    $helper = Mage::helper('helper/data');
    foreach ($value_ids as $value_id) {
        $helper->deactivateValue($value_id);
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    return;
}
```

Any ideas what would be causing this to not stay on the current page I'm on?
It's working on the Manage Products page, but interesting thing there, when I click on a page, the page number doesn't go into the URL, so it appears it's being submitted via POST or something on that particular page while mine is using GET. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Take a look @ your Grid.php, are you `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true)` and `$this->setUseAjax(true);`

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        ....
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
```

Comment: I also had to add `array('_current' => true)` to my redirect, then with the additions you suggested, it started working as one would expect. Thanks!